# C# Method returns Disposable that is not being used

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a method `Foo` that returns a `IDisposable` object. Oftentimes when this method is called, the return value is used. However, in this case I need the method to be called but don't need the return value. Is the correct thing to do to immediately call `Dispose` on it? If so, does it matter which of the below I do?

```
Foo().Dispose();
```

or

```
using(Foo())
{
}
```

or just

```
Foo();
```

Comment: This would be opinionated, but my vote is for the first option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an object implements IDisposable then you should call the Dispose method when you are finished with the object.  Dispose is meant to release resources that should not be held until a GC (Garbage Collector) cycle (or things that are not covered by the GC).  When the GC detects that an object is no longer used it will call the objects finalizer, but there is no way to predict when that will happen.  Therefore, the IDisposable interface was created so that programmers could explicitly dispose of an object's resources (it doesn't delete the object, the GC still does that).

I think I would prefer

```
Foo().Dispose();
```

but it really doesn't matter (between the first two).  If you just use "Foo();" then you are not respecting the Dispose pattern which would be incorrect.  You may want to try to determine what sort of resources the object is creating, perhaps there is a way to get the information you need without creating an object that needs disposing.

Comment: Note that `Foo().Dispose()` can throw NRE. `using` is materially better.

Comment: Very good point, a Dispose method may throw and exception and that should be considered.  Even a using statement isn't sufficient to protect against that (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ignoring those rare bad `Dispose` methods, it is way more likely for `Foo()` to return `null` and cause NRE.